# What is the precision of cudaEventElapsedTime()?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Say I invoke a `cudaEventElapsedTime()` and get the return value of `0.123456`. Then what is the exact time it suggests?

Answer (score 8):

[As stated in the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html#group__CUDART__EVENT_1g14c387cc57ce2e328f6669854e6020a5), the function `cudaEventElapsedTime` returns the elapsed time between two events in milliseconds. It has resolution of about 0.5 microseconds.

So value `0.123456` indicates that the elapsed time between the specified events is `0.123456` milliseconds.